# inserting mysql date field into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue submitting a form into a database once I have added a Submitted_Date field.

The errors are as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect date value:
> '2022' for column 'Submitted_Date'
>
> mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect date value: '2022' for column
> 'Submitted_Date'

Prior to adding in `$Submitted_Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Submitted_Date']));` I was also getting an error for incorrect listed fields on the binding.

The Submitted_Date field is a date input field so needs to be handled as 'NULL' value if a date has not been entered. Instead I also get a

> 'Incorrect date value: '1970'

Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
     <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      
            $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE orders SET Publisher_Email=? , Client_Name=? , Submitted_Date=? WHERE PC_Job_Number=?
            ");
            $Publisher_Email = $_POST['Publisher_Email'];
            $Client_Name = $_POST['Client_Name'];
            $Submitted_Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Submitted_Date']));
    
            $sql->bind_param("ssii", $Publisher_Email, $Client_Name, $Submitted_Date, $_GET["PC_Job_Number"]);  
            
            if (empty($Submitted_Date)) {
              $Submitted_Date = "NULL";
            }
            
            if($sql->execute()) {
                $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
            } else {
                $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
            }
        }
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE PC_Job_Number=?");
        $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["PC_Job_Number"]);           
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Any time you see 1970 in a date, it usually means that the strtotime() couldn't parse the given string value, and defaulted to the epoch of midnight Jan 1 1970. So first thing I'd do is check what string is going into that function, and then verify that strtotime() can correctly parse it. It might be that you have m-d-y and strtotime wants y-m-d or similar. You might use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) instead.

Comment: Is the first parameter of `bindparam` submitting your date as an integer, where you have already converted it into a string?
Also you need to check the posted value is empty, rather than than the result of `strtotime` which might have returned false.

Comment: Try `sql->bind_param("sssi"`. As DuckDensity alluded to, a date is a string, not a number.

Comment: To elaborate: if you cast the string `2022-01-01` to an integer, you get `2022`, as `-` is not a number (so don't do that). When no (or an invalid) date is passed to `strtotime` it will return `0` and 0 seconds after [1970-01-01 00:00:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) happens to be... 1970.